# How can I install python opencv on Heroku?

Tags: python, opencv, heroku

I tried using this custom buildpack https://github.com/gimlids/heroku-buildpack-python-opencv

But compilation fails due to a 15 minute timeout.

I also tried setting `COMPILE_TIMEOUT: 6000` but it Didn't help

Answer (score 2):

to get around the 15 minute compile time constraint for buildpacks on heroku, use [heroku-anvil](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-anvil) to compile the slug.

Comment: How exactly do you use heroku-anvil?

Comment: check out the docs on https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-anvil. It's installed as a heroku plugin. After installing, you would run heroku build -r myapp . This would compile the slug and release to the remote.

Answer (score 0):

I found a buildpack that worked well from a similar question about [Heroku and OpenCV with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879663/heroku-and-opencv-with-python).  I tried to replicate Diogo's work and added a few additional steps to add ffmpeg support and documented the steps in a blog post: [How to Install OpenCV on Heroku](http://scottlobdell.me/2014/10/install-opencv-heroku-ffmpeg-support/).

Answer (score 0):

use a 'one-off' dyno (aka `heroku run bash`) to compile, push the results to gihub (or store it anywhere else in the cloud), then use that url for your buildpack.

tl, dr; - avoid to re-compile each and every time.