# Heroku and OpenCV with Python

Tags: python, opencv, heroku, buildpack

I'm trying to install OpenCV on Heroku so my Python web app can use OpenCV.  How can I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Its for the fellow googlers who might have been facing the same issue.
Just simply change `opencv-python` in your **requirements.txt** to `opencv-python-headless`.

> opencv-python-headless is an opencv build that has no gpu support. The file libsm.so (P.S dont remember the name correctly) that is giving the error is for GPU support.

For reference :

[opencv-python-headless](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python)

Comment: This was simpler than other answers and solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Links posted by friism didin't work for me, so I created a custom buildpack that should be more than enough for the situation you described.

You can find the buildpack [here](https://github.com/diogojc/heroku-buildpack-python-opencv-scipy).

Comment: Thanks for posting this Diogo.  The links posted by @friism did not work for me either, and I will try this and let you know my success at a later point (at this point, it's for an old project that I ended up using Amazon EC2 for instead).

Comment: @Diogo I tried using your buildpack, but get this error. Any help much appreciated.                                                                                     
 2017-04-19T13:17:39.305177+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python app.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000`
2017-04-19T13:17:42.488675+00:00 app[web.1]: ruby: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so: undefined symbol: rb_enc_set_base
2017-04-19T13:17:42.503774+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named site

Comment: As of 2018, you can use a buildpack to install apt libs. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51004957/660711

Answer (score 3):

this question has also come up [on the Heroku forums](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/opencv-and-statically-compiled-python/105). It looks like there are a couple buildpacks you could look into:

- https://github.com/gimlids/heroku-buildpack-python-opencv
- https://github.com/hdachev/heroku-buildpack-opencv

Here's [how to use a custom buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/third-party-buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack).

Answer (score 1):

The following steps should solve the problem of openCV which you are facing -

1. Add the heroku-buildpack-apt to the BuildPack by pasting - https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt to add buildpack in dasboard.
   ScreenShot -
   [Adding through Dashboard -> Settings -> Add BuildPacks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXatf.png)
2. Then add the Aptfile in your Github base directory which contains -

```
libsm6 
libxrender1
libfontconfig1
libice6
```

- one library in each line. See Example [Github Link](https://github.com/Sharon-Samuel-Kerketta/Clothes-Classifier/blob/master/Aptfile)

Now build and deploy and you are ready to go!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. FYI, if you come across several questions for which you believe the exact same answer will solve all of the questions, you should not post the answer on all of the questions (they probably be deleted either by a moderator or an automated check for duplicate answers). What you should do is consider flagging the posts as duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like I am late to this thread but here's my solution that worked for me.
I needed to demo this API that makes use of OpenCV with Django DRF.

I tried all the solutions that consisted of adding **.buildpacks** and **Aptfiles** but none worked for me.

I ended up removing the `.buildpacks` file and `Aptfile` and added `opencv-python-headless` in the requirements.txt file as a replacement to `opencv-python`

Just doing that got the API working on python-3.8.0 runtime. The **libgl1** and such dependencies are for the GUI and GPU centric version that comes with `opencv-python`. So you can get away with `opencv-python-headless` or `opencv-contrib-python-headless`. The only buildpack you need is the `heroku/python` buildpack.

For more details, check options 3 and 4 [here](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/skvark/opencv-python)!

I have a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tinshade/cartoonize-api) for the same if you want to check it out!

**NOTE:** You can **not** use methods like `cv2.imshow()` with headless. You wouldn't be meaning to anyway but just a warning.