# How can I use OpenCV for Python in a Heroku app?

Tags: python, opencv, heroku, buildpack

I've been trying to find buildpacks online so that I can use my Python application that requires OpenCV on Heroku. I haven't had any luck so far, since all of the sources I've read are old. Can anybody lead me in the right direction? How would I go about creating my own custom buildpack?

Comment: Take a look at herokus multi buildpacks it may help https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app ; here is one for opencv https://github.com/slobdell/heroku-buildpack-python-opencv-scipy

Comment: Diogo's answer in this other question worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879663/heroku-and-opencv-with-python