# Installing OpenCV with Python support on Heroku

Tags: python, opencv, heroku

I'm attempting to install OpenCV for use with Python. The first install went great; however, I was missing the `cv2.so` file. I then added `-D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON` in hopes that it would create the `cv2.so` file for me.

Full command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${target} -D CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=${target} -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-fPIC" ..
```

Around 92%, OpenCV fails with the following:

```
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_python
    [ 92%] Building CXX object modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/src2/cv2.cpp.o
    Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/cv2.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/cv2.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
ERROR: Build failed, exited 2
```

Running the default version of Python 2.7.6 that Heroku installs. I've come across a few posts that suggest the need for `python-dev`, but it looks like the dev headers are already there ([Screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/0H3g3o3G1u1R)).

I'm using a custom [buildpack](https://github.com/6px-io/heroku-buildpack-python) if that's of any help.

Comment: Related problems with possibly working solutions: ["Heroku and OpenCV with Python"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19879663/2419207), ["OpenCV Python Linker Error"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20622583/2419207), ["How can I install python opencv on Heroku?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16949224/2419207)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Python needs to be compiled with the `--enable-shared` flag passed in so that `libpython2.7.so` and `libpython2.7.so.1.0` are created. OpenCV with the Python module requires `libpython2.7.so`.

To fix, compile python from source like so:

```
./configure --enable-shared
make
make install
```

Make sure to pass in the `-D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON` CMake flag when compiling OpenCV.